# How can I search and replace the end of a line across multiple files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
    broadcast('1')
    broadcast('2')
    broadcast('3')
    broadcast('4')
    broadcast('5')
```

I need it to become

```
    broadcast('1', 'addedstring')
    broadcast('2', 'addedstring')
    broadcast('3', 'addedstring')
    broadcast('4', 'addedstring')
    broadcast('5', 'addedstring')
```

Basically just adding a static argument, but I need to add it across many files.

I've tried built in search and replace across multiple files in both regex and non-regex modes, but I can't seem to figure out the right way to accomplish this. I've searched Google and SO very deeply for answers, but I can't figure out how to phrase my question properly in order to get relevant results, I keep getting results for newline and carriage return answers

Comment: users with 500k reputation very rarely give an incorrect answer

Comment: Well I don't know what to tell you @rioV8 https://i.imgur.com/KygyIwX.png

Comment: if the examples you show in the question do not match the cases in your file you get wrong answers, if you brush up on regex you can find the correct find/replace expression

Comment: Yeah, your `broadcast(@)` is quite different than the examples like ` broadcast('1')` you showed in your question.  Edit your question to show your actual test cases, the regex can be made generic enough to handle more cases than you showed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace in regex mode, across files:

```
Find:    \bbroadcast('(\d+)')$
Replace: broadcast('$1', 'addedstring')
```

The above would need to run in multiline mode.  Otherwise, use:

```
Find:    \bbroadcast('(\d+)')(\r?\n)
Replace: broadcast('$1', 'addedstring')$2
```

Comment: I feel like this is almost the answer, but unfortunately the find portion is returning no results